# Canvas HTML5: Objeto desaparece al moverlo con el mouse

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html2canvas

espero que me puedan ayudar u orientar , lo que pasa es que tengo que hacer es que en el canvas subir una imagen por un input tipo file y que se muestre , ademas poder moverla con el mouse que hasta ahi todo bien , el problema empieza cuando necesito insertar un cuadro estatico en la base del canvas con un numero insertado en ese mismo cuadro , pero al mover la imagen con el mouse se me elimina tanto el texto como el recuadro , espero que me puedan ayudar , lo necesito urgente y entiendo que cuando uno mueve el mouse se redibuja el contenido, pero no entiendo como podria realizar esto colocando un cuadro estatico y que no se borre

de antemano gracias a todos los que me leyeron y sobre todo a los que me puedan ayudar u orientar de alguna forma !

```js
var m = { 
        x: 0,
        y: 0 }; 
var img,
  dx = 0,
  dy = 0;

  let zoom = document.getElementById('zoom')

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = draw;
  img.onerror = failed;
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  console.log(this.files[0])
  ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,20);
});



function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("upper-canvas");
  var cw = (canvas.width = 200);
  var ch = (canvas.height = 250);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  ctx.fillText("Texto en el Canvas",100,50);
  // ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,20);
  var down = false;


  
  let mas =1;
  
  zoom.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
      mas =mas+ 0.2;
      img.style.transform = "scale(2.2)"
        ctx.scale(mas,mas)
      console.log(ctx)
      
      
  })



  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousedown",
    function() {
      down = true;
      var punto_de_agarre = oMousePos(canvas, event);
      dx -= punto_de_agarre.x;
      dy -= punto_de_agarre.y;
    }
  );
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mouseup",
    function() {
      down = false;
      m = oMousePos(canvas, event);
      dx += m.x;
      dy += m.y;
    },
    false
  );
  canvas.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function(event) {
      if (down) {
        clear();
        m = oMousePos(canvas, event);
        ctx.drawImage(img, m.x + dx, m.y + dy);
        console.log(event)
      }
    },
    false
  );

  function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // ctx.fillRect(200, 200, 0, 200);
  }

}
function failed() {
  console.error(
    "El archivo proporcionado no se pudo cargar como un medio de imagen"
  );
}

function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)

  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilos.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="file" id="input"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas">
        <canvas id="upper-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <button id="zoom">zoom</button>

    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Una observación: Para eliminar errores mueve las primeras 4 líneas de código de la función draw() al inicio del código y fuera de la función.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema estaría en que **no estas pintando nuevamente el cuadrado y el texto** cuando mueves la imagen.

Actualmente pintas el texto cuando se ejecuta el **draw**, pero cuando mueves la imagen dentro del canvas estas ejecutando la función **clean()** lo cual borra el canvas por completo incluido el texto, y luego vuelves a pintar la imagen pero no se pinta nunca más el texto, para que esto suceda debes tener algo como esto:

```
function repaint(img, x, y) {
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  ctx.fillText("Texto en el Canvas", 100, 50);
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 20);
}
```

y reemplazar en cada lugar donde estas borrando y pintando nuevamente la imagen por esta función de esa forma cada vez que se pinte la imagen posteriormente se pintara el texto y rectángulo.

**Acá un ejemplo online con tu código y esta función implementada.**
https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/ynqep53t/11

Espero te pueda ayudar.
Saludos.